# Better tabs management in Safari 6.x

Tags: software-recommendation, safari, safari-extensions, tabs

I'm looking for extensions to allow the Safari 6.x versions to manage a large number of open tabs better than the current implementation. In particular I'm looking for two features:

1. *Vertical tabs*. This is possible in Firefox by means of the extension [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/).
2. *App tabs*. In Firefox it is possible to pin tabs as *app tabs*.

Up to know I've found and tried several times [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) but it doesn't look great and it doesn't provide the features of *Tree Style Tab*. I would really like to move from Firefox to Safari, but for the problem of "I have too many useful extensions in Firefox." :)

Has anyone discovered extensions that add these features to Safari for OS X?

Comment: I don't know of any, but I would give my right arm for an extension that did this http://blogg.antrop.se/interaktionsdesign/redesigning-the-browser-window - well, someone's right arm, no point wasting a good one...

Comment: Myself as well, I love that extension for Firefox, and I just found one for Chrome as well, but when I am one my mac I really would prefer to use Safari, I guess I am just weird that way.

Comment: IMO the best Safari enhancer out there is glims (http://www.machangout.com/), but it doesn't appear to have the two features you require. :-(

Comment: This article on Mac Stories describes how to get vertical tabs in Safari *4*. I haven't tested it, and don't know if it still works in 5, but maybe this would work for you: http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/how-to-get-vertical-tabs-on-safari-4-106/

Comment: 6, even. Safari version numbers seem to be incrementing faster than I realise. :P

Comment: @AlexChan that link is for SafariStand which is in the question. However SafariStand is the only think I have seen that does any form of vertical tabs

Comment: Since Safari 7 is announced to make major changes in how tabs are handled, let's make this specific to Safari 6. Should 7 not be as different as it looks, we can edit that out - but we should focus on a narrow version since there clearly isn't an add-on that works across all versions that are out (let alone what's coming).

Answer (score 0):

[Safari does not allow extensions or plugins to mess with the tab bar.](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) If you really need this functionality, your best bet is to use Firefox with the plugin you mentioned.

Comment: However you can get the equivalent extra functionality with SafariStand it adds a vertical set of tabs and leves Safari's in place. However doe not work with Safari 7

Comment: Patching Safari with SIMBL is not a long-term solution.